# RSQLite typecasting issue

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm trying to write a table from a SQLite database into an R data frame and have hit upon a problem that has me stumped. Here are the three first entries in the SQLite table I would like to import:

```
1|10|0|0|0|0|10|10|0|0|0|6|8|6|20000|30000|2012-02-29 21:27:07.239091|2012-02-29 21:28:24.815385|6|80.67.28.161|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||33|13.4936||t|t|f||||||||||||||||||4|0|0|7|7|2
2|10|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|2|4|5|4|20000|30000|2012-02-29 22:00:30.618726|2012-02-29 22:04:09.629942|5|80.67.28.161|3|7||0|1|3|0|||4|3|4|5|5|5|5|4|5|4|4|0|0|0|0|0|9|9|9|9|9|||1|f|t|f|||||||||||||k|text|l|||-13|0|3|10||2
3|13|2|4|4|4|4|1|1|2|5|6|3|2|40000|10000|2012-03-01 09:07:52.310033|2012-03-01 09:21:13.097303|6|80.67.28.161|2|2||30|1|1|0|||4|2|1|6|8|3|5|6|6|7|6|||||||||||26|13.6336|4|f|t|f|t|f|f|f|f|||||||||some text||||10|1|1|3|2|3
```

What I'm interested in are columns 53 through 60, which, to save you the trouble of counting in the above, look like this:

```
|t|t|f||||||
|f|t|f||||||
|f|t|f|t|f|f|f|f|
```

As you can see for the first two entries only the first three of those columns are not NULL while for the third entry all eight columns have values assigned to them.

Here's the SQLite table info for those columns

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(observations);
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
** snip **
53|understanding1|boolean|0||0
54|understanding2|boolean|0||0
55|understanding3|boolean|0||0
56|understanding4|boolean|0||0
57|understanding5|boolean|0||0
58|understanding6|boolean|0||0
59|understanding7|boolean|0||0
60|understanding8|boolean|0||0
** snip **
```

Now, when I try to read this into R here's what those same columns end up becoming:

```
> library('RSQLite')
> con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = 'db.sqlite3))
> obs <- dbReadTable(con,'observations')
> obs[1:3,names(obs) %in% paste0('understanding',1:8)]
  understanding1 understanding2 understanding3 understanding4 understanding5 understanding6 understanding7
1              t              t              f             NA             NA             NA             NA
2              f              t              f             NA             NA             NA             NA
3              f              t              f              0              0              0              0
  understanding8
1             NA
2             NA
3              0
```

As you can see, while the first three columns contain values that are either `'t'` or `'f'` the other columns are `NA` where the corresponding values in the SQLite table are NULL and *`0`* where they are not - irrespective of whether the corresponding values in the SQLite table are `t` or `f`. Needless to say this is not the behavior I expected. The problem is, I think, that these columns are typecasted incorrectly:

```
> sapply(obs[1:3,names(obs) %in% paste0('understanding',1:8)], class)
understanding1 understanding2 understanding3 understanding4 understanding5 understanding6 understanding7 
   "character"    "character"    "character"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric" 
understanding8 
     "numeric"
```

Could it be that RSQLite sets the first three columns to the `character` type upon seeing `t` and `f` as values in the corresponding columns in the first entry but goes with `numeric` because in these columns the first entry just happens to be NULL?

If this is indeed what's happening is there any way of working around this and casting all these columns into `character` (or, even better, `logical`)?

Comment: My knowledge of SQLite is limited, but I'm confused as to how you have characters `t` and` `f` stored in a boolean column in SQLite. My understanding was that SQLite does not have a native boolean type, it simply stores them as integers 0 and 1. And further, column types are not enforced, so if you insert text into a boolean field, SQLite will convert the storage mode of the column.

Comment: I'm not expert on SQLite either (I had no idea column types aren't enforced, for one). The whole DB comes from a Ruby on Rails web app and I pretty much have to take it as is. But if the problem is that column types aren't enforced - and RSQLite obviously doesn't just use the R-equivalent of the column types - then how does RSQLite infer what class to assign to each column and is there any way of influencing that inference?

Comment: I'm not sure; I couldn't find a description in the documentation of RSQLite (but the real answer may be buried in the docs for the DBI package). Some on the [R-SIG-DB](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-db) would surely know the details of how RSQLite does type conversion. But before you ask there I would also double check your db and make absolutely sure that you have both t and f values in a column that becomes only NA and 0, because that sounds very strange.

Comment: I just checked again and best as I can tell, that's indeed the case. Thanks for the pointer. I'll take it up with the guys on R-SIG-DB

Comment: My suspicion as to how the typecasting is done was indeed correct (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/270389.html), so I've been trying to follow the suggestion of the aforelinked article to simply replace every `NULL` in these columns with `'NA'` and then taking it from there. However, I would love to do this in such a way that the SQLite DB isn't permanently changed. Is there a way to run the `INSERT` query to replace the `NULL`s, read the table into R and then to revert the `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is hacky, but it works:

```
# first make a copy of the DB and work with it instead of changing
# data in the original
original_file <- "db.sqlite3"
copy_file <- "db_copy.sqlite3"
file.copy(original_file, copy_file) # duplicate the file
con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = copy_file) # establish a connection to the copied DB

# put together a query to replace all NULLs by 'NA' and run it
columns <- c(paste0('understanding',1:15))
columns_query <- paste(paste0(columns,' = IfNull(',columns,",'NA')"),collapse=",")
query <- paste0("UPDATE observations SET ",columns_query)
dbSendQuery(con, query)

# Now that all columns have string values RSQLite will infer the 
# column type to be `character`
df <- dbReadTable(con,'observations') # read the table
file.remove(copy_file) # delete the copy

# replace all 'NA' strings with proper NAs
df[names(df) %in% paste0('understanding',1:15)][df[names(df) %in% paste0('understanding',1:15)] == 'NA'] <- NA
# convert 't' to boolean TRUE and 'f' to boolean FALSE
df[ ,names(df) %in% paste0('understanding',1:15)] <- sapply( df[ ,names(df) %in% paste0('understanding',1:15)], function(x) {x=="t"} )
```